# How to remove Libre.fm from Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, libre.fm

As I do not use Libre.fm, I'd like to remove it from the sidepane in Rhythmbox (Ubuntu Precise). I did it some time ago on of my machines. But now I cannot recall how I did it. :-( 
I could not find a plugin to deactivate, or a package to uninstall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libre.fm is part of the LastFM plugin

[image: pic]

Choose *Edit - plugins* and click of the Last.fm plugin.  You then will have the preferences button visible.  From the popup-dialog you can hide/show both services.